# Ajuda com validação de campos Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, formulário, validação

Fiz a seguinte função para validação de formulário em Jquery, mas ela ficou meio grande, e tenho +50 campos para validar, alguem sabe alguma forma de reutilizar está mesma função para os demais campos sem que eu tenha que copia-la e mudar o id?

```js
 $("#nome").blur(function(){

  var i="nome"
  var input=document.getElementById(i);
  var feed=document.getElementById("feed"+i);
  
  
  if ($(input).val().length<3) {
   $(input).addClass("erro");
   $(feed).removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
  }
   else{
    $(input).removeClass("erro").addClass("suscesso");
    $(feed).removeClass("show").addClass("hide");
   }
   
   })
```

```css
.suscesso{
    border-color: rgb(1, 182, 167)!important;
}

.erro{
    border-color: rgb(202, 2, 2)!important;
}
.show{
    display: block;

}
.hide{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="nome" required="">
      <div class="hide" id="feednome">
        Digite um nome valido
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer essa função genérica, você pode capturar o evento de todos os elementos 'input' com o atributo 'required'. Você saberá qual id/name recuperar, porque na função de Callback, retornará o 'this', que é o elemento que ocorreu o evento naquele momento.

```
$("input[required]").blur(function() {
    var input = $(this),
        feed = $("#feed" + input.attr("id"));

    if(input.val().length < 3) {
        input.addClass("erro");
        feed.removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
    } else {
        $(input).removeClass("erro").addClass("sucesso");
        $(feed).removeClass("show").addClass("hide");
    }
});
```

Tomei a liberdade de corrigir a escrita da classe "sucesso".

Fico à disposição, até mais.